# Which one is the best answer and why?

Tags: grammaticality

I am really looking for the answer. I will be happy to hear your answers. Thanks

Question:

> She brought her three friends, none of .... I have ever met before.
>
> 1. who
> 2. which
> 3. whom
> 4. whose

Comment: 1) welcome to ELU. You might want to visit [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) 2) It may be urgent to you, but we are not that kind of site and we do not do homework 3) this test is all over the web.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about offloading homework.

Comment: Suggested migration to ell.se

Comment: @Kris - Although I think it's good to point this particular user to [ell.se], I wouldn't want this particular question migrated there. The answer to the question is 3; what else is there to say? Let's save migration for the questions that are more suited to the SE format.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Whom" as it is semantically correct.No other option is correct.

Comment: It is not enough to state dogmatically that one is right or the other wrong; in order for your answer to be useful, it must explain *why*, with any links or citations as may be appropriate. The [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) may be of interest.